# 12.04 unable to communicate with Router WRT310N

Tags: 12.04, wireless, vaio, sony

I have a Sony Vaio VPCCB22FX running 12.04 and I'm trying to connect to my home router which is a Linksys WRT310N.

The connection is supposed to be OK. I connect to the router and I actually received an IP address correctly but I can't get into the Internet. I can't even ping my *default gateway* (Linksys Router). What could be the problem?

The router has connectivity to the Internet because I can use another computer and connect to that same router without problems. I can't ping my laptop from the router either.

Please, any ideas? I'm a Ubuntu newbie. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Does the result from "ifconfig" show two sections, one for "eth0" and one for "lo"?  If so, is the "inet addr" for eth0 the same network as your other computer (all number the same except the last)?  You might also try entering this command: `nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4`, and making sure everything is what you expect (you can post the results if you want).  You should be able to ping all the addresses shown in the result.

Comment: Ok, so this is what I get from the "ifconfig"
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:bf:97:65:00:76
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Interrupt:50
lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
RX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0

Comment: Is there a way to make my answer bigger? LOL is just that I couldn't publish everything I had to say hahaha

Comment: One thing that's missing from the "eth0" section is the "inet addr", among other things.  It seems like there is no ip address for some reason.  Did you definitely connect successfully?  You probably should check the "Network Connections" setup (right-click network on panel, choose "edit connections").

Comment: Got it!!! The computer and the router for some weird reason were not syncing the radio!! My laptop was using G and the router using N. After a while of reading packages with wireshark I found it haha. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Congratulations on finding the answer!

Comment: @DanielPorras As [we encourage under these circumstances](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), please post the solution you found as an answer to your own question. (You can even mark it as the accepted answer, two days after posting it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use command in terminal `sudo -i` then root password and another command `pppoeconf` and give your username and password provided by your ISP and enjoy Internet.

Comment: `sudo -i` takes the user's own password (created when they installed Ubuntu), [not the `root` password, which typically doesn't exist](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). Also, what's the advantage of this method over just running `sudo pppoeconf`?